# dygraph, bypass csv file x-axis and create own x-axis value

Tags: csv, dygraphs

I generate a csv file with data:

0.86,  -18.55,  -28.14
 -0.85,  -17.81,  -28.70
 -1.29,  -17.81,  -28.70
 -1.71,  -16.61,  -28.70
and so on.

Now i do not want dyGraph to use the first colum as the x-axis in the graph.
I want dygraph to generate a number for me starting at 0.
So the x-axis would be 0, 1, 2, 3 etc 
The data in the file would be only y-axis values.

Is this posible?
I searched the documentation/forum, but can't find it.

Regards,
Robertho

Answer (score 1):

dygraphs expects the first column to be x values. If you want your x-axis to be 0, 1, 2, etc., then you'll need to add a first column with those values.

Comment: Tried adding an extra column, and that works. But.. Adding a extra column is not what i want to do.  So there is no way to bypass this in dygraph?

Comment: No, dygraphs isn't a data processing tool. It's a charting tool.